# Trying to Create Template for Modal using ui Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
I am trying to create one template for Modal Window so I can reuse it.
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/W8UefqlNGqTWhBOXymWT?p=preview
Here is my code.

i don't know but I am getting http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A359
 error. And my Modal is not working.

On Button click I want to display Modal Window.

Comment: check modal section at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I checked that But I am trying to create Template for Modal

Answer (score 2):

```
#use $scope
`app.controller('YourController', ['$scope', '$modal', function($modal,$scope) {
  $scope.openModal = function () {
    $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'yourTemplate.html',
      controller: ModalController
    });
  };
}]);
<button data-ng-click="openModal()" role="button" class="btn primary" data-toggle="modal">Open me</button>`
```